# Plotting the same plot twice as subplots

Tags: julia, plots.jl, julia-plots

I want to create a plot with a couple of subplots using `Plots.jl`. Here's an example:

```
using Plots
gr()

p = plot(1:10, 1:10)
q = plot(1:10, 10:-1:1) 

plot(p, q)
```

[image]

That works exactly as expected! But say I want to use the same plot *twice* like so:

```
plot(p, p)
```

[image]

Hmmm. Only one plot. Perhaps I need to `copy` the plot first:

```
plot(p, copy(p))
```

but that give an error:

> ERROR: MethodError: no method matching
> copy(::Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend})
> Closest candidates are:
> copy(::Expr) at expr.jl:36
> copy(::Core.CodeInfo) at expr.jl:64
> copy(::BitSet) at bitset.jl:46
> ...
> Stacktrace:
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ORDD.png) top-level scope at REPL[216]:1

How can I plot the same subplot twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but try deepcopy() instead of copy(). deepcopy() often works on arbitrary objects which have no specific copy() method.

Comment: Thanks, Bill — that works perfectly. Can you comment on why it won't plot it twice _without_ copying first?

Comment: I don't know, but suspect it is due to how subplots are stored--Plots uses dicts for storing most of its substructures. If stored in a Dict,  you may not be able to put identical keys in the dict, and so the situation is forbidden. The people who maintain Plots may know.

Comment: It looks like it's potentially a bug: https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/3123